# when service discovery is down how microservices communicate with each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, apache-zookeeper, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

How microservice A communicate with microservice B when service registry is down?

i tried communicating with port id of the microservices B added in microservice A but in real time how it is possible and is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Service discovery is in some sense analogous to a dating app.  A service wants to find another one to talk to, so it uses service discovery to find an appropriate service.

So if one was looking for someone but didn't have a dating app, what would they do?  They might have a friend set them up with someone that the friend already knows.  That's exactly like manually configuring the service with the other service's details, and it's fragile if the friend has set you up with someone who disappears.  The friend is basically a somewhat limited (and perhaps unreliable, albeit in a different way) dating app, and manual configuration is really just another kind of (static) service discovery.  You can make it a little less static by allowing the configuration to be dynamically updatable without having to redeploy (e.g. having an API endpoint  that you hit to update the configuration), which is kind of like being able to call the friend after the other person disappears to ask if they know anybody else.

Another option might be to go to some place where a lot of people hang out and try to mingle.  This is kind of analogous to publishing messages to a queue/topic and hoping an interested service subscribes (this is pushing the analogy a bit, I know), and it also runs into the minor restriction that if you need service discovery to find your messaging system, you're back at square one.

The broader point is that it's like asking "how can I meet people when I can't meet people": you've built the answer into the question.